# WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend, django-settings

I use django 3.1.1 and Python 3.8.5. I want to create simple blog. I use some old code in which programmer used django 1.11 probably, so I change many things, but now I'm stuck

I get error

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

When I try to remove

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

This is my whole setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*s@w*wx_w23k5vp%c%*aatqr42dsu3m$^(et@a(yrx$(4j-u*o'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'blog',
    'taggit',
    'haystack',
)

MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-pl'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Send e-mails to shell.
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Haystack and Solr.
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/blog'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some middlewares are obsolet or moved/renamed. Try to use defaut middleware list from django 3:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application
> 'core.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.

When I added **the package 'hello'** which is not installed in my project to `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'hello', # 'hello' package doesn't exist
]
```

So, don't forget to install the packages which you need before adding them to `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`:

```
pip install <package>
```